# Referencing Parent in Cocoa

Tags: cocoa-touch, controller, uitabbarcontroller, parent-child

My question is about how to access the TabBarController from within one of its viewControllers.

Imagine a mainClass.m that adds tabBarController which has two viewControllers - viewController1 and viewController2.

In viewController1.m there is a game.  When the game is over, viewController1.m wants to tell tabBarController to display viewController2, but viewController1 has no reference to tabBarController.  How do I reference the viewController's parent?

How does one change tabBarItems from within the code for the current view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Via the tabBarController property of your view controller.

```
[ self.tabBarController setViewControllers: viewController2 animated: YES ];
```

Where "self" is viewController1

[tabController property of viewControllers](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIViewController/tabBarController)

[setViewControllers:animated: method of UITabBarController](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITabBarController/setViewControllers:animated:)

Also, technically, the tabBarController is not any view controller's parent. To say it that way is confusing how inheritance works in Objective-C. Your view controller's super class, or parent, is UIViewController.

Comment: Thank you.  That's fantastic that is is built into the viewController.

Comment: If it works for you, please don't forget to pick me as the answer. :P

Comment: You got it.  I wasn't sure how the parent child thing worked.